# multiple where statements in big select

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement, null, where-clause

I have 2 search params.

- I can pass nothing and then I must get all rows from DB.
      OR I can pass Param1 and get row where `ADB.param1=param1`
- OR I can pass Param2 and get row where `ADB.param2=param2`
- OR I can pass Param1 and Param2 and get row where `ADB.param1=param1
  and ADB.param2=param2`

Let's imagine that I have DB like

CarColor,CarType,CarEngineVolume,CarMakeName
param1 is CarColor
param2 is CarType
if I Select DB without sending params I must get the whole list of rows

> red,sedan,2.0,Honda
>   blue,sedan,3.0,Bmw
>   green,pickup,4.0,Ford

If I send only param2 for example "sedan"
I must get the following list

> red,sedan,2.0,Honda
>
> blue,sedan,3.0,Bmw

but if I send both params for example param1 "red" and param2 "sedan"
then I must get only 1 row

> red,sedan,2.0,Honda

If I deal only with one parameter in my where

```
WHERE (   (ADB.param1 = COALESCE(@param1, ADB.param1))
```

then when I send param1 I get only one row and all rows if param1 is null and its OK

but when I add second parameter check

```
    WHERE (   (ADB.param1 = COALESCE(@param1, ADB.param1)) 
AND (BDB.param2 = COALESCE(@param2 , BDB.param2))  )
```

I get nothing when sending only param1. 
But I still must get 1 row. But get nothing :(

Comment: Are you sending an empty string for @param2 or are you sending NULL?

Comment: if it is null I send DBNull while adding parameters

Answer (score 1):

use `OR` instead AND

```
WHERE (   (ADB.param1 = COALESCE(@param1, ADB.param1)) 
OR (BDB.param2 = COALESCE(@param2 , BDB.param2))  )
```

Comment: I can , but what will happen if I send both parameters then ? They will not be considered both

Comment: If param1 or param2 (any of both) matches, it will return the row

Comment: Yes but I want the row to be matched both of them.

Comment: @David, it would be good if you told what you are passing as param1 and param2 then it will be easy for understanding

Comment: They are search params.
I can pass nothing.
OR I can pass Param1
OR I can pass Param2
OR I can pass Param1 and Param2
To search DB

Answer (score 0):

You can use this.

```
WHERE ( ( @param1 IS NULL OR ( ADB.param1 = @param1 )) 
    AND ( @param2 IS NULL OR ( BDB.param2 = @param2 ))
    AND ( ADB.param1 IS NOT NULL OR ADB.param2 IS NOT NULL ) )
```

Comment: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IS'.'

Comment: could you check the parenthesis in your query again? I tested it and this query does not give this exception.

Comment: I've checked it through SQL directly and  If I send null params I receive all rows but only first row contains data.

Comment: "If I send null params I receive all rows but only first row contains data" don't you want to get all rows for null params?

Comment: I want to get all rows with their data if I send no params. It means I have no specific search options so I want to list the whoe DB as it is.

Comment: then you should check the column names at the select part.

Comment: names are OK, because if I send both parameters Select works > search for the corresponding row and shows it.

Comment: if you have only param1 and param2 in your select, it shows null for null, its normal. I don't understand the problem?

Comment: I get data from DB. Lots of rows. If I send no search params then I get all rows.
If I send only first search param then I must search for all rows where first param equals search param. If I send both params then I must search for the row where both params will be.

Comment: do you want to extract null records from the result?

Comment: i made an upate